# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP Call in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am using Confident Technologies Image Captcha and within their technologu I need to post to their servers, which in return will then pass back the HTML code. See: https://login.confidenttechnologies.com/docs/restful

I have produced a an VBScript for this but I can get the results I need.  The Function is :

```
FUNCTION CreateSecurity()
  Dim nURL : nURL = "http://captcha.confidenttechnologies.com/captcha"
  Dim SendStr : SendStr =     "api_username=jqcsgvsi47g9BEgncu2Mb9pINE4W5tEYNPIwMHFR&api_password=pHm5IDZhLiaeY8raDStdEyoRiBeqoTSMDeFxkWcM&customer_id=K9PWSU6s&site_id=storeboard"
  Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  xmlhttp.open "POST", nURL, false
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xmlhttp.send(SendStr)
  Response.write xmlhttp.responseText
  Set xmlhttp = nothing
END FUNCTION
```

I simply call this function where I want the capture to appear.  However when I call the function I get the following result:

> Bad Request
>
> site_id may not be blank.
>
> api_password may not be blank.
>
> api_username may not be blank.
>
> customer_id may not be blank.

See Results: http://www.storeboard.com/join_now_new.asp

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1) I found [this article](http://objectmix.com/xml-soap/87408-sending-post-variables-using-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-3-0-a.html), the result of which would be to change your content type header to `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

2) Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze the request and make sure the headers and form data are sent.

Good luck